# Pointer value loses scope

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

In the method callTest I declare a pointer to an int called testPtr.
I then pass it to the method test where it is assigned. Since the pointer is no longer nullptr I can print the value.  However, when I leave the scope of a::test, I see the pointer is null again. I am perplexed as to the reason why.

```
class a
{
public:
   a();

protected:
    void a::callTest()
    void test(const int* intPtr) const;

private:
    int mIntTest;
}

a::a() : mIntTest(7)
{

}
void a::callTest()
{
    printf("a::callTest mIntTest = %d\n",mIntTest);
    int* testPtr = nullptr;
    // set the value of the pointer
    test(testPtr);
    if (testPtr == nullptr) {
        printf("a::callTest testPtr STILL NULLPTR\n");
    } else {
        printf("a::callTest test ptr = %d\n",*testPtr);
    }
}

void a::test(const int* intPtr) const
{
    intPtr = &mIntTest;
    if (intPtr != nullptr) {
        printf("a::test intPtr = %d\n",*intPtr);
    }
}

output:
s::callTest mIntTest = 7
a::test intPtr = 7
a::callTest intPtr STILL NULLPTR
```

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: If you want to change what the pointer *points to* rather than just changing the value of what it already points to, you need to pass your function a reference or a pointer (double pointer) to the pointer itself, that you can update.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Thanks your answer makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the pointer by reference:

```
void a::test(const int* & intPtr) const
                    //  ^  like this
```

otherwise you are passing it by copy, and changes made inside the function will not be visible to the caller. This is no different than  when you pass an `int` by copy vs by reference, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Thanks much. Your solution makes a lot of sense and it solved my problem.